# vba case doesn't insert formula

Tags: vba, excel, case, formula

I have been working on this code for a while and can't seem to get it to work.  I am trying to insert a formula in column AP based on the value of the cell in the same row of column D.  The code cycles through but doesn't put the formulas in the cells of column AP.

```
Sub DTCNFScontract()
Sheets("Cognos Data").Select
Range("A2").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim rCell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("D2:D" & LastRow)

'Insert Hash Calculation Based On SO Type and VLOOKUP
Sheets("Cognos Data").Select
For Each rCell In Rng.Cells
Select Case Rng.Select
Case rCell = "Z006"
  Rng(, "AP").Formula = "=IF(AND(VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-41]:C[-40],2,0)<3,VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-41]:C[-39],3,0)<50),""Hash"","""")"
Case rCell = "Z002"
  Rng(, "AP").Formula = "=IF(AND(VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-36],2,0)<3,VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-35],3,0)<50),""Hash"","""")"
Case rCell = "Z013"
  Rng(, "AP").Formula = "=IF(AND(VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-36],2,0)<3,VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-35],3,0)<50),""Hash"","""")"
Case Else
  Rng(, "AP").Formula = """"
End Select
Next rCell

'Copy Calculations and Paste As Values
Columns("AP:AP").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Cognos Data").Select
Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean the formula does not appears at all, or did you check column AS?  Rng(, "AP") actually put formula in Column AS since it start counting from Column D

Comment: Your code is working but I think you intended `Rng(, "AP").Formula` to be `rCell(, "AP").Formula`.  The releative offset is Col AS instead of AP.  If that's not what you want, try this: `Cells(rCell.Row, "AP").Formula`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `D` as the criteria for `AP`, your `Select Case` should take `rCell.Value` as the reference point. See code below.

```
Sub DTCNFScontract()

    Dim CognosSht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set CognosSht = Sheets("Cognos Data")

    With CognosSht

        LastRow = CognosSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count    
        Set Rng = .Range("D2:D" & LastRow)

        'Turn off calculations first so that no calculations are triggered while inserting formula.
        'That will add too much execution time.
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End With

        'Insert Hash Calculation Based On SO Type and VLOOKUP
        For Each rCell In Rng
            Select Case Trim(rCell.Value)
                'NOTE: VLOOKUP FORMULAS ARE INCOMPLETE!
                Case "Z006"
                  .Range("AP" & rCell.Row).Formula = "=IF(AND(VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-41]:C[-40],2,0)<3,VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-41]:C[-39],3,0)<50),""Hash"","""")"
                Case "Z002"
                  .Range("AP" & rCell.Row).Formula = "=IF(AND(VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-36],2,0)<3,VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-35],3,0)<50),""Hash"","""")"
                Case "Z013"
                  .Range("AP" & rCell.Row).Formula = "=IF(AND(VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-36],2,0)<3,VLOOKUP('Cognos Data'!C[-21],'AP Hash Build Pivot'!C[-37]:C[-35],3,0)<50),""Hash"","""")"
                Case Else
                  .Range("AP" & rCell.Row).Formula = """"
            End Select
        Next

        'Calculate everything after inserting formulas.
        'An alternative is to use `Evaluate` instead while inserting formulas
        'but that can be slower.
        With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic       
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With        

        'Copy Calculations and Paste As Values
        With .Columns("AP:AP")
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
        End With

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range("A2").Select

    End With

End Sub
```

Let us know if the above works.

Comment: Hi Nanashi.  I used your code and it seems to be only inserting the formula for Case Else (all rows in column AP are showing "".  Some of the rows in column AP should say "Hash" based on the data in the report.  Any ideas on why they all say ""?

Comment: Probably because they all only satisfy the condition for `Case Else`. On which columns are `Z006` and the like located, in column `D`?

Comment: Yes, the Z006, Z002, and Z013 are all from column D.

Comment: I've edited the code above. Kindly copy and test again. If it still doesn't work, please put a breakpoint on this line: `Set Rng = .Range("D2:D" & LastRow)` by clicking on the left-hand bar of this line in the VB editor. Run the code again, and hover your cursor on `LastRow` and kindly reply back with the value.

Comment: I updated the code with your changes.  It still only inserts the 'Case Else' formula.  I added the breakpoint you suggested and the 'LastRow' = 32.

Comment: Based on the data that I'm using, lines 2-4, 11-16, and 18-22 should all end up with "Hash" in their respective cells in column AP.

Comment: Would you mind uploading the file somewhere and replying with the link here? I have a few guesses but unless I see the data, I can't be too sure.

Comment: This is my first time using this site or anything like it.  Any suggestions on where I should upload the file?

Comment: @Rick: Use something like Dropbox or Wikisend. Doesn't have to be anything fancy, just make it public. Make sure it's filled with dummy data if it's company property.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28711616/DTC_NFS_Contract_Rpt_Hash_Build.xlsb

Comment: Two things: Your `VLOOKUP` formula is incomplete. It's missing the first argument. Next, change `Select Case rCell.Value` to `Select Case Trim(rCell.Value)`. The values in `D:D` have extra whitespaces, which you failed to mention in your code above. Cell value should be exact in comparison. Running it without fixing the `VLOOKUP` formula arguments will result in the cells getting `#N/A` errors.

Comment: @Rick: Glad to help. I am inclined to say to quit using the `R1C1` notation and use the exact formula instead in your VBA code, but whatever works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Hi your code is near perfect, In this `Rng(, "AP").Formula` since you are not giving row index, you code is copying the formula in the same cell(First cell in your range), so the formula is getting replaced every time and while iterating through cells ,its not putting the formula in different cells. I have modified your code, to insert the row index . Change the sheet name and formula to your accordance.

```
Sub DTCNFScontract()
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim rCell As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("D1:D10")
x = 1
'Insert Hash Calculation Based On SO Type and VLOOKUP
Sheets("sheet1").Select
For Each rCell In Rng.Cells
Select Case Rng.Select
Case rCell = "Z006"
Rng(x, "E").Formula = "=A3*6"

Case rCell = "Z002"
Rng(x, "E").Formula = "=A3*2"
Case rCell = "Z013"
Rng(x, "E").Formula = "=A3*13"
Case Else
Rng(x, "E").Formula = """"
End Select
x = x + 1
Next rCell

'Copy Calculations and Paste As Values
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```